# How to send a message on deleteing a message after bot restarting?

Tags: discord.js

I want the bot to send a message to the channel if someone deleted a message.
It is working, but if i restart the bot and try it again it is not deleting the messages that sent before the restarting

why?

this is my code:

```
client.on('messageDelete', messageDelete => {
     if(messageDelete.channel.id === "563966341980225536" || messageDelete.channel.name === "general"){
       messageDelete.channel.send("Working !");
     }
});
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [how to fix events not working after restarting the bot](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55868601/how-to-fix-events-not-working-after-restarting-the-bot)

Answer (score 0):

```
client.on('messageDelete', messageDelete => {
     if(messageDelete.channel.id === "563966341980225536" || messageDelete.channel.name === "general"){
       messageDelete.channel.send("Working !");
     }
});
```

The above code is subscribing to an event. Assuming an API is healthy, you are only going to get one event every sent to you. So, if you have an event sent to you, and you restart the bot before it is done handling the event, nothing is going to happen. Unless you have a mechanism on your end that is queueing these events and persisting them, restarting the bot means it won't capture that messageDelete fully with the handler. This is just how events are by design.